# Repeat numpy vector-matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: numpy

I have a set of vectors (n), another set of vectors (s) and a set of 3x3 2D arrays (T).

```
n = np.array([
    [[1, 2, 3]],
    [[2, 2, 3]],
    [[3, 2, 3]],
    [[4, 2, 3]],
    [[5, 2, 3]],
    [[6, 2, 3]]
])
s = np.array([
    [[1, 1, 5]],
    [[2, 2, 5]],
    [[3, 3, 5]],
    [[4, 4, 5]],
    [[5, 5, 5]],
    [[6, 6, 5]]
])

T = np.array([
    [[1, 2, 3],
     [1, 2, 3],
     [2, 2, 3]],

    [[2, 2, 3],
     [3, 2, 3],
     [4, 2, 3]],

    [[3, 2, 3],
     [5, 2, 3],
     [6, 2, 3]],

    [[4, 2, 3],
     [7, 2, 3],
     [8, 2, 3]]
])
```

Right now, my current code loops through n, s, and then T:

```
result = np.array(n.shape[0], s.shape[0], T.shape[0])

for i in range(n.shape[0]):
    for j in range(s.shape[0]):
        for k in range(T.shape[0]):
            result[i][j][k] = np.sum(n[i] * T[k] * s[j].T)
```

I tried to use np.apply_along_axis but it requires a 1D array to operate on.  Ideally, I'm trying to work out a solution that doesn't require any for loops.

I tried to get `np.tensordot()` working (and do this in two operations), but so far no success.

Anyone have ideas on a more 'numpy-ish' way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
np.einsum('imn,jnm,kmn->ijk', n, s, T)
```